# Get border edges of mesh - in winding order

Tags: algorithm, geometry, mesh, triangulation, convex-polygon

I have a triangulated mesh. Assume it looks like an bumpy surface. I want to be able to find all edges that fall on the surrounding border of the mesh. (forget about inner vertices)

I know I have to find edges that are only connected to one triangle, and collect all these together and that is the answer. But I want to be sure that the vertices of these edges are ordered clockwise around the shape.

I want to do this because I would like to get a polygon line around the outside of mesh.

I hope this is clear enough to understand. In a sense i am trying to "De-Triangulate" the mesh. ha! if there is such a term.

Comment: ok, Imagine if my surface had a big dent in the side of it reaching into the inner part of it's shape, but with a thin neck to it - . Would the convex hull follow that dent around? or would it skip right over it because it is only considering the maximum extents of the shape? Hard to explain without a picture.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Boundary edges are only referenced by a single triangle in the mesh, so to find them you need to scan through all triangles in the mesh and take the edges with a single reference count. You can do this efficiently (in `O(N)`) by making use of a hash table.

To convert the edge set to an ordered polygon loop you can use a traversal method:

1. Pick any unvisited edge segment `[v_start,v_next]` and add these vertices to the polygon loop.
2. Find the unvisited edge segment `[v_i,v_j]` that has either `v_i = v_next` or `v_j = v_next` and add the other vertex (the one *not* equal to `v_next`) to the polygon loop. Reset `v_next` as this newly added vertex, mark the edge as visited and continue from 2.
3. Traversal is done when we get back to `v_start`.

The traversal will give a polygon loop that could have either clock-wise or counter-clock-wise ordering. A consistent ordering can be established by considering the [signed area of the polygon](http://geomalgorithms.com/a01-_area.html). If the traversal results in the wrong orientation you simply need to reverse the order of the polygon loop vertices.

Comment: Hi Darren, I followed the algorithm you suggested above. And it worked first time! Thank you. It is completely logical how it works so thanks for the precise description you gave me. I have already found the edges that exist in one triangle only on the mesh. So all i needed was the traversal algorithm to order the vertices correctly.

Comment: How would you efficiently make a hash that collides? i.e. an edges hash should be the same even if their start and end are flipped.

Comment: @TJHeuvel: one way is to call the hash function on a copy of the edge in which the indices are first sorted.

Answer (score 8):

Well as the saying goes - get it working - then get it working better. I noticed on my above example it assumes all the edges in the edges array do in fact link up in a nice border. This may not be the case in the real world (as I have discovered from my input files i am using!) In fact some of my input files actually have many polygons and all need borders detected. I also wanted to make sure the winding order is correct. So I have fixed that up as well. see below. (Feel I am making headway at last!)

```
    private static List<int> OrganizeEdges(List<int> edges, List<Point> positions)
    {
        var visited = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
        var edgeList = new List<int>();
        var resultList = new List<int>();
        var nextIndex = -1;
        while (resultList.Count < edges.Count)
        {
            if (nextIndex < 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < edges.Count; i += 2)
                {
                    if (!visited.ContainsKey(i))
                    {
                        nextIndex = edges[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < edges.Count; i += 2)
            {
                if (visited.ContainsKey(i))
                    continue;

                int j = i + 1;
                int k = -1;
                if (edges[i] == nextIndex)
                    k = j;
                else if (edges[j] == nextIndex)
                    k = i;

                if (k >= 0)
                {
                    var edge = edges[k];
                    visited[i] = true;
                    edgeList.Add(nextIndex);
                    edgeList.Add(edge);
                    nextIndex = edge;
                    i = 0;
                }
            }

            // calculate winding order - then add to final result.
            var borderPoints = new List<Point>();
            edgeList.ForEach(ei => borderPoints.Add(positions[ei]));
            var winding = CalculateWindingOrder(borderPoints);
            if (winding > 0)
                edgeList.Reverse();

            resultList.AddRange(edgeList);
            edgeList = new List<int>();
            nextIndex = -1;
        }

        return resultList;
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// returns 1 for CW, -1 for CCW, 0 for unknown.
    /// </summary>
    public static int CalculateWindingOrder(IList<Point> points)
    {
        // the sign of the 'area' of the polygon is all we are interested in.
        var area = CalculateSignedArea(points);
        if (area < 0.0)
            return 1;
        else if (area > 0.0)
            return - 1;        
        return 0; // error condition - not even verts to calculate, non-simple poly, etc.
    }

    public static double CalculateSignedArea(IList<Point> points)
    {
        double area = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
        {
            int j = (i + 1) % points.Count;
            area += points[i].X * points[j].Y;
            area -= points[i].Y * points[j].X;
        }
        area /= 2.0f;

        return area;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Traversal Code (not efficient - needs to be tidied up, will get to that at some point) Please Note: I store each segment in the chain as **2** indices - rather than 1 as suggested by Darren. This is purely for my own implementation / rendering needs.

```
        // okay now lets sort the segments so that they make a chain.

        var sorted = new List<int>();
        var visited = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

        var startIndex = edges[0];
        var nextIndex = edges[1];

        sorted.Add(startIndex);
        sorted.Add(nextIndex);

        visited[0] = true;
        visited[1] = true;

        while (nextIndex != startIndex)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < edges.Count - 1; i += 2)
            {
                var j = i + 1;
                if (visited.ContainsKey(i) || visited.ContainsKey(j))
                    continue;

                var iIndex = edges[i];
                var jIndex = edges[j];

                if (iIndex == nextIndex)
                {
                    sorted.Add(nextIndex);
                    sorted.Add(jIndex);
                    nextIndex = jIndex;
                    visited[j] = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (jIndex == nextIndex)
                {
                    sorted.Add(nextIndex);
                    sorted.Add(iIndex);
                    nextIndex = iIndex;
                    visited[i] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return sorted;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends actually on how triangular mesh is represented in memory. If you use [Half-edge data structure](https://www.flipcode.com/archives/The_Half-Edge_Data_Structure.shtml), then the algorithm is extremely simple, since everything was already done during Half-edge data structure construction.

1. Start from any boundary half-edge `HE_edge* edge0` (it can be found by linear search over all half-edges as the first edge without valid `face`). Set the current half-edge `HE_edge* edge = edge0`.
2. Output the destination `edge->vert` of the current edge.
3. The next edge in clockwise order around the shape (and counter-clockwise order around the surrounding "hole") will be `edge->next`.
4. Stop when you reach `edge0`.

To efficiently enumerate the boundary edges in the opposite (counter-clockwise order) the data structure needs to have `prev` data field, which many existing implementations of Half-edge data structure do provide in addition to `next`, e.g. [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib#readme)