# coplanar equations of a plane

Tags: python, plane

My question is similar to this post although that poster is concerned with adjacent faces [How to merge adjacent coplanar faces on a mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290365/how-to-merge-adjacent-coplanar-faces-on-a-mesh/36269017#36269017)

I am able to extract the plane equations for each triangular facet from an stl and then convert them to a numpy array

```
ax + by +cz = d
plane_eq=np.array([a,b,c,d])
```

How could I compare the plane equations and determine which ones are coplanar and eventually merge them into one large plane equation?

The sympy library has a class for this but I am not able to get it working properly with Anaconda. http://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/geometry/plane.html#Plane.is_coplanar

Also, I did try an approach where I took the normals and compared them with one another via the dot product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two `[a, b, c, d]` vectors representing planes are coplanar iff they are just a scalar factor multiple of each other.

You could just normalize each vector and compare.

```
def are_coplanar(plane1, plane2):
  # planes are given as [a, b, c, d], ax+by+cz=d
  return numpy.all(plane1 / length(plane1) - plane2 / length(plane2) == 0)
```

where `length` is vector magnitude, `numpy.linarlg.norm` or roll your own, `length = lambda a: numpy.dot(a, a)**0.5`.

To handle the case that planes are degenerate (`[0, 0, 0, 0]`), use equivalent but safe:

```
return numpy.all(plane1 * length(plane2) - plane2 * length(plane1) == 0)
```

But in general it would probably make most sense for you to normalize all plane equations (divide by length but check for degenerate), so that checking them is a simple equality.

#### Naive way

You could also check that all ratios in `plane1 / plane2` are equal, but need to properly handle zeros in `plane2`:

```
def are_coplanar(plane1, plane2):
  first = numpy.where(plane2)[0][0]  # TODO: handle all zeros
  return numpy.all(plane2 * plane1[first]/plane2[first] - plane1 == 0)
```